# How to write a SQL query to combine the specific columns of the multiple rows of single table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a Oracle SQL query. I have a table name stop :

and having two rows as follows :

```
STOP_ID LOCATION CONTRACT STOP_ORDER PICKUP_DT (IN TIME) DROP_DT (OUT TIME)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
183     ABC         507     1    6/20/2016 6:25:00 AM    6/20/2016 6:25:00 AM 
184     CSD         507     2    6/20/2016 9:20:00 AM    6/20/2016 9:20:00 AM
```

Now i want the output in this way , I need to show the (in and out times) from location CYB to BNY .

IN time of the CYB and OUT time of the BNY in the output

```
CONTRACT  PICKUP_DT (IN TIME)  DROP_DT (OUT TIME)  LOCATION
--------------------------------------------------------------
507      6/20/2016 6:25:00 AM  6/20/2016 9:20:00 AM  CYB->BNY
```

Please help

I need the query output for the all contract ids that exists in the stop table for last 2 year on the base of one more column create_date in the stop table .

The criteria would be same as i explained that for every contract id there will be a two stops (1 and 2) .

Comment: will there always be two sets of related rows?  How are they identified?

Comment: yes there will be two set of rows related to the contract and the mentioned locations (CYB and BNY) in the table. There are other locations also but i need to work on the mentioned locations

Comment: But you show two different contract numbers (507,508) .  How do you relate the two rows? There has to be some common value to link the two rows together.

Comment: yes by mistake i mentioned different contract id's but contract id will be same in both of the rows

Comment: Will there be a point where there will be more than 2 stops and when that situation occurs will you need to show the stops like `CYB->BNY->SFY->WTV`?

Comment: will `stop_order` always be a sequence (1, 2, 3 etc)

Comment: No, for the locations CYB and BNY there will be only a 2 stops

Comment: yes, for the contract id, stops will always in the sequence (1,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c1.contract, c1.pickup_dt, c2.drop_dt, c1.location||'->'||c2.location
from stops c1
inner join stops c2 on ( c1.contract = c2.contract)
where c1.contract = 507
and c1.stop_order =1 
and c2.stop_order = 2
```

Comment: I am getting only the dates but  not along with the time in the query output .As in the question you can see that date is same but time is different for all rows . In the db data is in the format that i posted as a question. I need time also  in the output with the date

Comment: datatype used in the oracle for the pickup_dt and drop_dt are DATE

Comment: Need some modification in the query that i need to execute it for multiple contracts and for particular date range  .As stops table contains multiple contracts having same locations and same stop order. please help

Comment: That is an exercise left for you.  Answered question as it was posed.   Put in a bit of effort, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you want to use analytical functions.  This avoids doing self-joins.

```
select contract, pickup_dt, drop_dt, location
from (
select contract
    , lag(pickup_dt) over (partition by contract order by stop_order) pickup_dt
    , drop_dt
    , stop_order
    , location || '->'||lag(location) over (partition by contract order by stop_order) location
from stop)
where stop_order = 2
```